# Grouping two elements at a time

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I have a list of data and I need to perform a grouping operation two elements at a time. I tried to making it myself, but it takes too much time. I have a large list, so I need a faster way.

Here is an example input:

```py
lst = [["title1","content1"],["title2","content2"],["title3","content3"],["title4","content4"],["title5","content5"]]
```

and here is an example output:

```py
lst = [["title1","content1 content2"]["title3","content3 content4"],["title5","content5"]]
```

Comment: What do you mean by regroup? Can you give an example of what the desired output should look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `zip_longest()` to handle two elements at a time:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest
result = [[first, ' '.join([second, fourth])] if fourth is not None else [first, second]
    for (first, second), (_, fourth) in zip_longest(lst[0::2], lst[1::2], fillvalue=(None, None))]
```

This outputs:

```py
[['title1', 'content1 content2'], ['title3', 'content3 content4'], ['title5', 'content5']]
```